# Dictionary cannot be bridged from Objective-C -> Issues in Swift

Tags: swift, fmdb

I have been porting some objective-c code over into swift and I am trying to get the result set as a dictionary and then pack each dictionary (equivalent to a row from the db) into an array. But I am getting this error message "Dictionary cannot be bridged from Objective-C". I have read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_46) from apple but still I am no further along towards a solution. Any ideas? Thanks.

This is the line where the error is:

```
resultsArray.append(resultSet!.resultDictionary() as Dictionary<String,String>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the awesome *[robertmryan](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/343)* reposted here for convenience:

This will happen if your database has an null values (which return `[NSNull null]` objects) or numeric values (which return `NSNumber` objects). You can fix this by defining `resultsArray` as:

```
var resultsArray = Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>()
```

Or, I personally prefer:

```
var resultsArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()
```

And then when adding objects, I'd

```
resultsArray.append(resultSet!.resultDictionary() as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

or

```
resultsArray.append(resultSet!.resultDictionary() as [String: AnyObject])
```